# Angular 10 reactive form reset angular material datepicker not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

My Application is in Angular 10 I am using reactive form and I have Angular material date-picker, I am setting [max] value dynamically. how can I reset angular material datepicker.

I used this code but it doesn't reset the validations

```
   this.taskForm.controls['TaskReminderDate'].reset();
```

and also tried

```
  this.taskForm.get('TaskReminderDate').reset();
```

component.html:

```
    <mat-form-field id="taskreminderdate" appearance="outline" class="reminderdatefield" *ngIf="isReminderRequired">
                      <input matInput [matDatepicker]="TaskReminderDate" placeholder="Reminder date *" [min]="sDate"  [max]="mDateReminder" formControlName="TaskReminderDate">
                        <mat-label>Reminder date *</mat-label>
                        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="TaskReminderDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                        <mat-datepicker #TaskReminderDate></mat-datepicker>
                    </mat-form-field>
```

Option one I select today and I set the [max] to today for TaskReminderDate

[image]

I select 16 I mean today. now I click on option two, the option two resets the reminder datepicker and set the max to tomorrow and min is today for all the options
because I had selected on the first option selection the today now when I select 16 which is today it works but when I select 17 which is tomorrow it gives validation error see the image for option 2

[image]

I select 16 here it works

[image]

When I select 17 it gives validation error see below image

[image]

Comment: Please share the code.

Comment: added the datepicker code

Comment: Your control is TaskReminderDate: `this.myform.get('TaskReminderDate').reset()`

Comment: I tried this.myform.get('taskReminderDate').reset() same the validation error.

Comment: @MJX it is case sensitive

Comment: set the default value to **mDateReminder** to the variable.

Comment: The default value is today, but I change it dynamically based on the options I select

Comment: I try to reset the value to based on the options I select, it resets the value if you see the images the problem is when I select the value greater it gives validation error. see images

Comment: You may try this "this.taskForm.controls['TaskReminderDate'].setValue(null);"